# Calculating number of pages when the number of lines of even pages is different from odd

Tags: calculus, functions, problem-solving

I have an array and I want to divide them into page according to preset page size, but
the maximum number of **rows** in a **even page** is **n** and the maximum of rows in **odd** page is **m**, with n different from m.

How do I find out the total number of pages?

Comment: What have you tried? That way, we know what exactly we can help you with.

Comment: The only idea is to calculate the page count in a loop, removing the lines that go into a page at each iteration, but what I'm looking for is a mathematical formula.

Comment: It might help to solve an easier problem first. If you always take 2 pages at a time, can you find a simple formula for how many pages you'll need?

Comment: @ConMan it's an idea, what I can't do is how to insert the concept of odd and even page into the formula

Comment: You could use a function that's defined conditionally - for example, $f(k) = a$ when $k$ is even and $f(k) = b$ when $k$ is odd. If you're looking for something "clever", you could use something like the modulus, or the floor and ceiling functions, to emulate that behaviour.